# Como quitar "anucios /publicidad" en el header.php de un tema personalizado de Wordpress, insertatos por GoogleAdsense de manera ''AUTOGENERADA''?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme, google-adsense

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimados, saludos cordiales.
Como podran apreciar llevo horas intentando solucionar el problema de la insercion de anuncion de parte de GoogleAndsense en el 'Header' de la pagina web, he buscado en varias paginas, sin embargo no logro encontrar la forma de restringir de alguna menera que el auto generador de anuncion no se coloque en esa seccion(google-auto-placed).
Por lo que agradeceria grandemente que me ayudaran con la solucion, de este grave inconveniente que genera en la interfaz de la web.

Ya procedi a revisar en el hosting los permisos de las carpetas y archivos, los cuales se encuentran bien según los estándares(0755 y 0644) en contratados en este Foro

(http://www.forosdelweb.com/f118/eliminar-publicidad-que-introduce-mi-header-php-1035369/),

que comparto anteriormente el link, en donde charlan acerca de este mismo problema, pero en mi caso no logro dar con la solución luego de intentar los pasos que describen en ella.
Por favor, solicito amablemente su ayuda, me encuentro bastante desorientado con la posible solución que deba llevar a cabo en esta situación.

Adiconalmente comparto el codigo del **'header.php'** de la pagina frontal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    
    <header class="site_header siteHeader_gridContent">

        <div class="navHeader_content ">

            <div class="site_logo">

                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(site_url('/')); ?>">     
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>./assets/img/dixi_logo_gun_proweb_min_shine_v0.svg" alt="DixiLogo">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="site_navBin">
                   
                <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        "theme_location" => "nav_main_menu",
                        "container" => "nav",
                        "container_class" => "site_navBarMenu"
                    );
                
                    wp_nav_menu($args);
                ?>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="site_hero_content">
        
            <h1 class="txt_col_prime_white txt_pos_center">
                <?php echo get_field("hero_title"); ?>
            </h1>

            <p class="txt_col_prime_white txt_pos_center">
                <?php echo get_field("hero_title_content"); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    
    </header>
```

El cual al revisarlo lo encuentro normal, por lo que no se que archivo o carpeta se debería restringir o eliminar para que la inserción en el 'header' no se presente.

Agradezco de antemano su amable atención

Comment: ¿Verificaste qué realiza la funcion wp_head()?, yo creo que de ahi sale el problema ya que el banner se ubica entre las etiquetas HEAD, por otro lado, podrias verificar tambien las librerías JS que está cargando, ya que no creo que sea una funcionalidad de WP.

Comment: Revisa el código del plugin, lo mas probable es que este usando el hook wp_head o algún otro do_action, tendrás que buscar en los ajustes del plugin pero si no hay nada ahí tendrás que si o si revisar el código y leer la documentación haber si encuentras filtros que te permitan modificarlo.